# Populating the Kiva basket returns page not found

Tags: php, api, curl

I'm developing a donation site which has kiva integration according to this documentation: http://build.kiva.org/docs/linking_to_kiva/baskets. I'm trying to set the basket on kiva.org by posting to this url (using curl): http://www.kiva.org/basket/set, but since today I get 404. I did not made any modifications on the site since a month. Does anyone experience this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kiva has changed the basket set URL to https only, so the correct URL is: https://www.kiva.org/basket/set.